# Keras, tensorflow importing error in sublime text and spyder but working in command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

In command-line, everything seems fine. But when I am importing tensorflow in sublime text or spyder it gives the following error -

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/himanshu/Desktop/iii.py", line 1, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

When I am importing keras

```
import keras
```

following is the error

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/himanshu/Desktop/iii.py", line 1, in 
>       import keras
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/**init**.py", line 3, in 
>       from . import utils
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/**init**.py", line 6, in 
>       from . import conv_utils
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in 
>       from .. import backend as K
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/**init**.py", line 89, in 
>       from .tensorflow_backend import *
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

**Note - I am using pip for my python packages and not conda**

Comment: Seems like your IDEs are using a different environment than your command line.   Can you do a `import sys; print(sys.executable)` both from the command line python and within the python of Spyder or Sublime?

Comment: It is the same - "/usr/bin/python3"

Comment: Oh, I see. It can't find the cublas library. This suggests a difference in the lib paths.  Can you run `import os; print(os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'])`, again in your various versions of python?

Comment: This is the output when run on console - usr/local/cuda/lib64:

Comment: This is the output from Spyder - Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-5281a39f963c>", line 1, in <module>
    import os; print(os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'])

  File "/home/himanshu/venv/deeplearning_keras/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None

KeyError: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH']

Answer (score 0):

This typically occurs when multiple versions of python are installed with different paths. You can check to see if you have multiple installations by opening up the IDLE terminal and using

```
import sys

sys.version
sys.path
```

These commands will print the system PATH and version of the current instance of python. Use this in both IDLE and the command line terminal to see where each differ. Once you know which version is the one you want then just remove the other. You could also remove all python instances and then reinstall a clean python environment but then you would have to re-install all of your modules using pip.